# TranslateOptions.newBuilder().setApiKey(Constants.API_KEY).build().getService() is deprecated. Which is the new method to achieve that?

Tags: android

TranslateOptions.newBuilder().setApiKey("API_KEY").build().getService() is deprecated. Which is the new method. Please give me a example source code in Android.